# Is there a way to know when presenting a UIViewController fails?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have `UIButton` in a `UIViewController` that run a background task. If this task fails, a `UIAlertController` is created and presented. Once the user click "Ok" on this alert view, I reset some parameters.

The problem is that as it's a background task, the user can enter in another `UIViewController`, then I get a warning `Attempt to present` which is normal as the user is not on the UIViewController that was supposed to present the alert.

Is there a way to know when presenting a UIViewController fails (a way to catch this warning)?

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. In your link he asks why it fails but I know why it does, I am just wondering how to detect it.

Comment: I removed possible duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to "catch" the warning.

Try to present alert controller in the top-most view controller, such as `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController` if they are applied in your case.

Comment: If the user is on another view controller, the alert view becomes pointless. I guess I'll have to find another way